# Converting SQL to LINQ (left join on two fields)

Tags: sql, linq

I need help to convert this expression to LINQ.
In this example:

```
TableA[IDTABLE_A, NAME]
TableA[IDTABLE_B, IDTABLE_A, REL]


SELECT     *
FROM       TableA a
LEFT JOIN  TableB b
ON         a.IDTABLE_A = b.IDTABLE_A
AND        b.IDTABLE_B = 3
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should provide some code showing your effort to solve the problem. Start with implementing the entity classes with all the mapping and navigation properties according to referential constraints in your db.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
var query = from a in data1
                        join b in data2.Where(x => x.BID == 3)
                        on a.AID equals b.AID into ab
                        from c in ab.DefaultIfEmpty()
                        select new
                        {
                            AID = a.AID,
                            AName = a.AName,
                            BName = c == null ? "No Records" : c.BName
                        };
```

Complete Working Fiddle [Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/9RFE3A).